# Alternative Enumeration Environment

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, enumitem, amsthm

I have a theorem which lists a bunch of properties, and then I prove them one-by-one.  Because the proofs are long, it looks awkward when every line is automatically indented by the `enumerate` environment.

Is it possible to define a new environment, call it `enumproof`, which is exactly the same as the `enumerate` environment, but *without the indentation*?

Bonus challenge:
Is it possible to re-define the `enumerate` environment so that it knows when it is inside the `proof` environment (from the `amsthm` package)--and in that case, it automatically switches to act like the `enumproof` environment (meaning, without the indentation)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent I want this enumeration to look normal:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hello
\item to
\item you
\end{enumerate}

\begin{proof}
But I want this enumeration to have no extra indentation:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hello
\item to
\item you
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I usually write normal paragraphs. The initial number is sufficient to give clues and a long indented text is not so nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Bonus one can be done by checking the command `\@currenvir`. Therefor I am using the command `BeforBeginEnvironment` provided by `etoolbox`. The changings of the environment `enumerate` are local because they will be passed only inside the group `proof`.

For your result you need the following settings:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=*,listparindent=\parindent,parsep=0pt}
```

The example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{%
   \def\@tempa{proof}%
   \ifx\@currenvir\@tempa
     \setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=*,listparindent=\parindent,parsep=0pt}%
   \fi}  
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\noindent I want this enumeration to look normal:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hello
\item to
\item you
\end{enumerate}

\begin{proof}
But I want this enumeration to have no extra indentation:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hello \kant[1]\kant[2]
\item to
\item you
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}


\begin{enumerate}
\item Hello
\item to
\item you
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @jamaicanworm: Please see my edit

Comment: @jamaicanworm Clearly your question wasn't so clear, since both Marco and I interpreted it the same way.  But Marco has now solved both your problems, so I've deleted my answer.

Comment: This is good, but there is still one problem:  if I have a paragraph break within an `\item` (inside an `enumerate` inside a `proof`), for some reason the new paragraph is still not indented as normal paragraphs should be...

Comment: @jamaicanworm Are you sure Marco's code doesn't do what you want?  I've updated his code slightly, and shown an example image.  Does this do what you want?  If not, you really need to be clearer on what the problem is.

Comment: Before it didn't do what I needed, by thanks to your edit now it does.  Thank you Alan!